# Order of items in a ListView

Tags: .net, winforms

I am using a ListView in Detail view.

How do you get the order of items as displayed in a ListView? (For example enable/disable of grouping)

Comment: Are you sure you are looping on the listview items from 0 to n and not on the original datasource? if any...

Comment: I tried foreach on the `.Items` and for loop `.Items[0]`. Both give back the original order I added the items, and not the displayed order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you can use is sorting. As the question is very broad, [here is a link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort) that contains numerous methods available for you.

Your actions should be:

1. Get data
2. Sort it
3. (Re)Bind it to the UI control

Ideally you would use a separate thread for this (like Task, Background worker etc)

Comment: For the record: I'm not sure if this will work. A ListView can sort items by itself. It can have groups in any order. Items can be in groups, not necessarily all. Group display can be toggled on/off. It has no DataSource property. So after "binding", the visible order of items can be totally different than the order in the source data.